# I use RVM where does webrat live? How can I find it?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, webrat

How can I find /lib/webrat/core/session.rb if I use RVM?

I have no idea how to search using terminal on my OSX.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to be writing software you should become very familiar with the command-line. Though there are a lot of GUI-based programming tools, a lot of what you'll need to do will involve the command-line, especially if you have to do anything with mainframes or Linux/Unix. My machine at work is a Mac but I easily spend 50% of my time at the command-line connected to other machines as I work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `gem env` into your terminal, look under the `GEM PATHS:` option. That is where your gems are stored for that version of Ruby with RVM. Go to there and you should be able to find webrat and the file you are looking for.

For example, on my system the GEM PATH is:

```
/Users/ctcherry/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p248
```

Leading to webrat:

```
/Users/ctcherry/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p248/gems/webrat-0.7.3
```

And the file in question:

```
/Users/ctcherry/Developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p248/gems/webrat-0.7.3/lib/webrat/core/session.rb
```

Comment: Thank you ver much! Great to know about gem env

Answer (score 2):

`gem contents webrat` should give you the paths of all files of the webrat gem.